Can a DHCP Server detect Windows version?
How can a DHCP server distinguish between Windows 10 and  Windows 7 clients?
I want to identify the Windows version of the clients using the vendor class, and assign the specified settings.
I am unable to configure anything on the clients.
I want the DHCP server to be able to detect the Windows version by itself.
Is there a way to do this?

What vendor class do you see the clients sending? Is it actually different between the clients?

Is there a way to do this? create reservations for the limited number of known Windows 7 hosts.

Do you have managed switches?  Put the win7 machines in their own VLAN, which will have a different IP block to the win10 machines.

There may be other ways to differentiate the Windows 7 boxes, e.g., perhaps they have MAC addresses from the same ancient vendor?

@HagenvonEitzen i dont want use mac or user class

@Criggie i know. but without vlan

@javadbasirat what's your end-goal here ? Stocktaking or isolating w7 hosts from w10 hosts with different IP ranges in the same IP network ?   Do you want to give the two groups a different DHCP option each, like Gateway or Nameserver or something ?   This whole post could be an XY problem.

@Criggie My goal is for the DHCP Server to be able to detect whether the Windows version making the request is Windows 10 or 7. I don't want to make changes on the clients, and I know this can be done using MAC address and user class. I want to achieve this using vendor class.

@javadbasirat That is not your goal. That is only a way of achieving your ultimate goal. What is your actual goal? Why do you need to handle the two operating systems distinctly?

@jcaron This is a research project given to me by my professor, and I am trying to figure out how to achieve this goal.

@javadbasirat thank you for sharing the true reason - this is your homework, and not a real-world question.

No, it can't.
The vendor class supplied by Windows clients ("MSFT 5.0") is extremely crude. Windows 7/10/11 can't be separated.

The vendor class option doesn't do the trick, as Zac67 wrote already, but the DHCP Fingerprints (number and order of Requested DHCP options in option 55) should differ
from version to version. Classing DHCP clients by fingerprint is not supported by all DHCP servers, though. If fingerprinting is a possibility for you, you'll find a database at https://api.fingerbank.org/devices.
On request of the OP, I'd like to add that both ISC dhcpd (see example at
https://github.com/daviswr/dhcpd.fingerprint/blob/master/fingerprint.conf)
and ISC Kea support classifying clients based on fingerprinting.
(There's at least one commercial DHCP server which supports it, too).

Thank you very much.
I checked the messages, and the number and order of option 55 in Windows 10 and 7 are different. But how should I set this condition in DHCP?

@javadbasirat Fingerprinting by looking at the order of DHCP options is not exactly a normal feature as order should not normally make a difference in a request. It depends on whether your DHCP server software of choice has such a feature available and, if not, then you'd have to switch to one that does or add it to an open source DHCP server yourself.

@penguin359 In the DHCP Discover request from the client, the Option 55 request list is different for these two Windows versions. I think the DHCP server should be able to determine which Windows version is making the request by looking at this option.
